# Getting RefererNotAllowedMapError from GAPI whereas the restriction pattern defined seems to match the referring URL

Tags: google-maps-api-3

*A.S/ probably for another SE.com site: why "referer" is spelt with only r at Google's?*

Anyway, here we go again with another occurrence of `RefererNotAllowedMapError`.
I couldn't find my answer in the existing Q&As.

Hypothesis:

- I have a local website that includes a GMap.
- It displays and works
  fine provided I remove all restrictions on that key, from the Google
  API console.
- But the browser will receive a `Google Maps JavaScript
  API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError` whenever I add a referrer
  restriction, which *seems to match* the refering URL.
- The referrer, where the map is being called form, is:

  `https://app.developr.online.local/projects?p=name-asc-0-20-1&a=createProject`

**Below is my GAPI KEY security configuration:**
[image: GAPI KEY configuration]

**Below is the corresponding console output:**
[image]

To be noted:
If I add a trailing asterisk when declaring the referer, validating that entry will clear it anyway. To me it means: "that's ok, we're covering  trailing `/*` already.".

My question: what pattern should I enter as a referrer (2 r's) to have it recognised by GAPI security layer?
I've tried a few things, I didn't get a cigar.
Thank you.

Comment: You need the wildcard (trailing asterisk).  You need `https://app.developr.online.local/*` in the referrer field.  I don't know what you mean by "validating that entry will clear it anyway", but it needs to be there (or you need to use the complete URL in the error message: `https://app.developr.online.local/projects?p=name-asc-0-20-1&a=createProject`).

Comment: That's what I thought I'd need too...but it won't stay! This is what I tried to explain: if I add it, it will get cleared: if I add a trailing "/*", as you can see on the picture uploaded, the API console will clear the asterisk...

Comment: This what I have for my website: `*.geocodezip.com/*` (and `geocodezip.com/*`); seems to be an issue with the user interface.  Maybe try it without the protocol (`https://`).

Comment: Same thing: upon adding the entry, the asterisk gets removed automatically. Can you show me a screenshot of your entry on the GAPI console please?